# Querying a mariadb database works in phpmyadmin, but not from php

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Note: I know that prepared statements are a more secure method. My final code always uses prepared statements, but this is the final step of my work flow as prepared statements can be more difficult to debug.

My method of sending queries to the database from php is:

```
<?php
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    $sql = "<sql statement goes here>";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        echo "<error message goes here>";
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
?>
```

I have tested it and it works for most valid sql commands.

Then, in the process of developing, it returned the error message. I changed the sql command to a known good, and it worked fine again. So I echoed the broken command into the browser using `echo $sql;`, selected it, copied it to phpMyAdmin and it executed exactly as I wanted it to.

> UPDATE products SET reserved = 20600 WHERE product = 'product1';
>   UPDATE products SET reserved = 1600 WHERE product = 'product2';

Executing `mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)` returned:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UPDATE products SET reserved = 1600 WHERE product =
>   'product2'' at line 1

Why won't it work through the method above when it works through phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process involving `mysqli_stmt_init()`, `mysqli_stmt_prepare()`, and `mysqli_stmt_execute()`, can only execute one command at a time. phpMyAdmin can execute multiple commands at once. The command given in the statement was actually two, separated by a ";". This is why phpMyAdmin was able to run it.

Comment: There is http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php but I'd recommend not using that..injections with that will be very bad.

Comment: @user3783243, my knowledge of prepared statements has never extended beyond "they protect against injections because magic" despite all my best efforts to learn. Would using prepared statements for all inputs make the multi-query safe?

Comment: multi-query doesn't not have prepared statements.

Comment: @mickmackusa Ah. I'll avoid using it then. Thanks.